# Hiding check mark in CheckBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

In my windows phone application I am using some checkboxes. When I checked a checkbox, I need to hide the check mark from that checkbox. To identify the checked items I am changing the background image of the checkbox. The "IsChecked" property of the checkbox should not be changed. Can I hide the check mark from the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Click `Edit Template - Edit a copy` in `Expression Blend` and change `Checked` `Visual State` to what do you want